# On the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I am following [this tutorial](http://mccormickml.com/2014/03/04/gradient-descent-derivation/), and I couldn't understand 2 mathematical rules, I am looking for a very simple, step-by-step logic please:

T**he Power Rule**: $\frac{d}{dx} u^n = nu^{n-1}\frac{du}{dx}$

**The Chain Rule**: $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$

***P.S*** And yes, I did search but could not find fair explanation.

Comment: Should be small f in chain rule. Also, u is a function of x, it is called g(x) in the chain rule. Note $f(g(x))=g(x)^n$ in that case.

Comment: In your statement of the chain rule, the capital $F$ should be a lower case $f$. What is it about the chain rule that you don't understand?  How to derive it? How to use it?  Can you use the chain rule to compute the derivative of the function $h(x) = \sin(x^2)$?

Comment: @Emil I fixed the typo.

Comment: @littleO Let's focus on the Power Rule please, as far as I know: $x^n = nx^{n-1}$ But how come we multiply by `du` again !

Comment: You can probably think of it as something like $f'(g(x))=\frac{\partial f(g(x))}{\partial g(x)}=\partial_{g(x)}f(g(x))$ and $g'(x)=\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}=\partial_x g(x)$

Comment: The statement of the first rule might be more clear with different notation. Suppose that $h(x) = u(x)^n$. Then $h'(x) = n u(x)^{n-1} u'(x)$. This result can be shown using the chain rule, as follows. Notice that $h(x) = f(u(x))$, where $f(y) = y^n$. The chain rule tells us that $h'(x) = f'(u(x)) u'(x) = n u(x)^{n-1} u'(x)$.

Comment: @littleO What is $u(x)^n$? Is it a another function? because in the tutorial it's just: $(h(x^i)-y^i)^2$ And Where can I find this rule in math?

Comment: You're missing a subscript $\theta$ there, it should be $(h_\theta(x^i) - y^i)^2$. I don't find the notation in the tutorial to be super clear. It's important to recognize that in the tutorial we are differentiating a function of $\theta$, with $x^i$ and $y^i$ held fixed. What the tutorial calls $h_\theta(x^i)$, I might prefer to call $h_i(\theta)$. Define $J_i(\theta) = (h_i(\theta) - y^i)^2$. Then $J_i'(\theta) = 2(h_i(\theta) - y^i)h_i'(\theta)$. That notation is more clear to me.

Comment: @littleO A shorthand version of it is without the subscript theta. Thanks anyway, I hope I get an answer that clears out my confusion.

Comment: The subscript $\theta$ is crucial, though, because we are differentiating with respect to $\theta$, so we must show that the function we are differentiating is a function of $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u=u(x)$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}u^n &= \frac{d}{du}u^n\frac{du}{dx}\\
&= n u^{n-1}\frac{du}{dx}
\end{align}

Also, let $y=g(x)$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}f(y) &= \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}f(y) \\
&= g'(x)f'(y)\\
&=g'(x)f'(g(x))
\end{align}

[Reference](http://%20www3.ul.ie/cemtl/pdf%20files/bm2/RulesDifferentiation.pdf)

Comment: @Yahya Sure thing, Rule 7 in the following pdf is a generalisation of your query. http://www3.ul.ie/cemtl/pdf%20files/bm2/RulesDifferentiation.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'll use Taylor expansion to define the derivative: $f'$ is the only number (/linear application) such that:
$f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h=\omicron(h)$

One have:
$f(g(x+h))=f(g(x)+g'(x)h+\omicron(h))=f(g(x))+f'(g(x))\bigl(g'(x)h+\omicron(h)\bigr) +\omicron(h)$

Hence the desired result:
$f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))-f'(g(x))g'(x)h=\omicron(h)$